# regex just adding = breaks match

Tags: javascript, regex

Why with this regex

https://regex101.com/r/wYUZCO/1

```
(category\s+(\w+))(\s*=\s*)?(?:\s+(\w+))?(?:\s+(\w+))?
```

I can match

```
category fruits pear orange
```

but not

```
category fruits = pear orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching the space after `=` twice; first using \s* after the `=` in your regex, and then with `\s+` on `(?:\s+(\w+))`.

You could resolve this easily in many different ways, but this one is probably the simplest:

`(category\s+(\w+))(\s*=\s*)?(?:\s*(\w+))?(?:\s+(\w+))?`

(note, I changed `(?:\s+(\w+))` to `(?:\s*(\w+))`, in order to match a space 0+ times instead of 1+ times.)